# ArrayList does not save my Values

Tags: java

following: I create a ArrayList with an Own Object which keeps two int(x,y)

But I only get 0 instead of the number. I don't see why it does not work.

```
public class Snake {

public class SnakeBody {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    SnakeBody(int x, int y){
        x = this.x;
        y = this.y;}
}

protected ArrayList<SnakeBody> SnakeBody = new ArrayList<SnakeBody>();
protected PointF Fruit;

protected boolean GameStarted = false;

//Constructor
public Snake(){}

public void startSnake()
{
    if(!GameStarted)
    {
        GameStarted = true;
        SnakeBody.add(new SnakeBody(1,14));
        SnakeBody.add(new SnakeBody(2,14));
        SnakeBody.add(new SnakeBody(3,14));
        int itemcount = SnakeBody.size();
        Log.d("Snake.java:Game started: ", "" + itemcount);
        for(int i=0; i<itemcount; i++){
            Log.d("First Snake created: XY->", "" + SnakeBody.get(i).x + ":" + SnakeBody.get(i).y);
        }
    }
}
```

That's what I got then as Log.d Output:

Snake.java:Game started:﹕ 3

First Snake created: XY->﹕ 0:0

First Snake created: XY->﹕ 0:0

First Snake created: XY->﹕ 0:0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to change

```
SnakeBody(int x, int y){
    x = this.x;
    y = this.y;
}
```

to

```
SnakeBody(int x, int y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

What you are actually doing is assigning values of your class to the received parameter, it will never update the position of `SnakeBody`

By the way, I think it is a bad practice to name the parameter of your constructor the same as the class variable as if you ommit the `this` keyword, it is not clear what is assigned to what.

Answer (score 3):

Look at your constructor:

```
SnakeBody(int x, int y){
        x = this.x;
        y = this.y;}
```

That's copying the value *from* your instance field *to* the parameter, in both cases. In other words, you're overwriting the useful data (the value that the caller passed in) with the value from the otherwise-uninitialized field (which will always be 0). You want it the other way round:

```
SnakeBody(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
}
```

Note that this has nothing to do with the `ArrayList` aspect - you could observe the same thing just by writing:

```
SnakeBody body = new SnakeBody(1, 2);
System.out.println(body.x); // 0
```

It's always worth trying to pinpoint *exactly* where the issue is, trying to remove bits of code one at a time until the behaviour changes.

(It's also a good idea to make all fields private, but that's a slightly different matter.)